# Trigger is not working in Amazon Aurora when executing Liquibase changeLog

Tags: mysql, rds, amazon-aurora

I create a table and the data type of id is BINARY(16).

Then I create a trigger, to generate an id for each row.

```
- changeSet:
  id: 1586934810000-1
  author: qwe
  changes:
    - sql:
        sql: create trigger ins_document_request_types before insert on document_request_types for each row set new.id = unhex(replace(uuid(), '-', ''));

- changeSet:
  id: 1586934810000-5
  author: michael-eb
  runOnChange: true
  changes:
    - loadUpdateData:
        columns:
          - column:
              name: name
              type: STRING
        file: db/changelog/data/document-request-types.csv
        primaryKey: id
        tableName: document_request_types
```

Then I load data from CSV file, it doesn't have id for each row.
and I get an error: *Field 'id' doesn't have a default value*

All these steps are executed by Liquibase.

I have tried to insert a row by myself by the console of ubuntu, the trigger worked, but when I use IDEA to do same thing,  it doesn't work.

Which step I did wrong? How to fix it?